# Does Transcendence Increase Troops Survivalibility?

Tags: iron-marines

In Iron Marines there is a skill called transcendence

https://ironmarines-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Transcendence

The skill is paired with other upgrades. For example, the mech gets ejection seat. And the army got last man standing.

The other upgrades make the units survive. If a mech is destroyed, the surviving pilot will get another mech. If an army is destroyed, the last man is invulnerable and the squad can recover.

But what about the empyrian units?

They got a spirit that keep fighting. Then what? After a while can the squad recover? It's kind of weird that the other 2 upgrades increase the longetivity of the squad but the empyrean doesn't